# Функция для ввода строк в Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Пробовал использовать `input`, но она выводит ошибку при вводе строки. Как можно в консоле вводить строки? Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.readline()
asdawda
'asdawda\n'
```

Comment: true way !

Answer (score -1):

```
#по-моему так
s = str(input())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> x=input("введите число:")
введите число:1
>>> print x
1
>>>
```

python 2.7 ни каких проблем